# 7 wonders rules about science in wonders

Tags: 7-wonders

There's a rule in 7 wonders that science buildings that were used/sacrificed for building of wonders in your city are counted towards your total science points in the end of the game. That would mean you can build the same building but use resources required for building of wonder and retain the benefits in the end of the game. Is this the case or did i interpret something wrong?

Comment: Could you please quote the exact section of the rulebook you are referencing here? While I don't currently own a copy, I have played the game extensively and never encountered this rule, and it's certainly not something the (Android) app version does either.

Comment: No need. Checked the english version of rules and compared to the Croatian it makes sense. Sometimes translations may be more confusing.

Comment: I'd suggest adding that as an answer in case anyone else comes across this question; [Stack Exchange explicitly encourages self-answered questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: The rulebook doesn't say what the Croatian translation may imply.

It specifies exactly the opposite:

> 2.b. Build a Stage of a Wonder
>
> To build each stage of his or her Wonder, the player will use a card of their
> choice as a construction marker:
> To do that, the player must pay the price shown on the Wonder board and
> not the one shown on the structure’s card.
> The player then plays the card, face down, half hidden under the Wonder
> board to show that this stage of their Wonder is now built.
> **The card then has no other effect, and is not considered to be a structure.**

Comment: Thanks for input. The Croatian translation version which I have has a different wording than english and is somewhat confusing in this regard.